# Probability of all ball colors drawn with replacement?

Tags: probability

Suppose there are $x$ colors of balls, $1$ ball for each color ($x$ total balls), you draw a ball $n$ times with replacement (putting back the ball you'd just drawn). What is probability that you draw each color of balls at least once?

My guess was:
$$P(x,n)= \frac{C(n-1,n-x)}{C(x+n-1,n)}$$
I thought it was correct because $P(x,n<x)=0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(x,n)=1$. But $P(10,10) \neq \frac{10!}{10^{10}}$, which I think is the probability at $x=n=10$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I would've thought that the denominator would be $x^n$?

Comment: You need inclusion - exclusion principle. The number of ways in which one color is missing is $(x-1)^n$, two colors missing is $(x-2)^n$ and so on. Thus the probability is $\left(x^n - \binom{x}{1}(x-1)^n + \cdots \right)/x^n$

Comment: This is the "Coupon Collector's Problem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: @Muralidharan: I personally get a negative value when plugging in x=n=10, would you look into it?

Comment: @awkward: Alright, that page is a bit too advanced for me to comprehend. I suppose it's trying to calculate the mean value of number of trials taken to collect all the coupons. It's tackling the same problem, but I've got no clue as to how to derive the answer to my question from it.

Comment: For $n=10, x=10$, we will get $10!/10^{10}$. The numerator is $10^n - \binom{10}{1}9^{10} + \cdots = \Delta^{10}f(0)$ where $f(x) = x^{10}$ and $\Delta$ is the difference operator. This is a standard result from Difference Calculus.

Comment: The numbers are (10000000000, 1), (3486784401, 10), (1073741824 ,45), (282475249, 120), (60466176, 210), (9765625, 252), (1048576, 210), (59049, 120), (1024, 45), (1, 10)
and the alternate sum is 3628800 which equals $10!$

Comment: @Germaniac You are correct, the Wikipedia entry addresses the mean number of trials required but does not address the distribution function of the time to get a complete set of coupons.  But googling "Coupon Collector's Problem" will lead you to other sources of information.  Here is one with a more detailed discussion than Wikipedia's: https://probabilityandstats.wordpress.com/tag/coupon-collector-problem/